# How to subscribe object from service in Angular 2/5?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-services

I have issue where I want to receive data into my property component after they came from the server.

I made something like this in Service:

```
private events: Event[] = [];
eventChanged = new Subject<any>(); // Edit: added an observable

constructor(private http: HttpClient) { 
    this.http.get<Event[]>(this.baseUrl)
    .subscribe(events => this.events = events);
  this.eventChanged.next(this.events.slice()); //Edit: added an information to subscribers that events list changed
}
getEvents(): Observable<Event[]> {
    return this.eventChanged.asObservable();
}  // Edit: now I use this method to enables subscribers to observable

        /* I don't use that method after Edit
        showAllEvents(): Event[] {
            return [...this.events];
        }
        */
```

And then I use method `showAllEvents()` into mine component like this:

```
private events: Event[] = [];
private calendarEvents: CalendarEvent[] = [];
subscription: Subscription; // Edit: Added a Subscription

    getInterestedEvents() {
       // this.events = this.el.showAllEvents(); <-- I changed it into observable
   this.subscription = this.el.getEvents()
    .subscribe(
    (events) => {
      this.events = events;
    });
    this.events.forEach(eachEvent => {
        let calendarEvent: CalendarEvent = {
            start: subDays(startOfDay(new Date()), 1),
            end: addDays(new Date(), 1),
            title: eachEvent.name,
            color: colors.red
        }
        this.calendarEvents.push(calendarEvent);
    })
}
```

I don't know how to make `this.events` to wait for data from service. Any ideas? On every page it looks different and now I feel like a fool.

**Edit**

I made a subscribe and observable but still `this.el.getEvents().subscribe...` dosen't return any data in my component.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create a subscription in your service that notifies if event list changed

```
eventChanged = new Subject<Event[]>();
```

in your component, you'll want to subscribe to the eventChanged, in case event list has changed

```
this.subscription = this.eventService.eventChanged
  .subscribe(
    (event: Event[]) => {
      this.events = events;
    }
  );
```

Then add a `next` in your service to notify of event changed every time any component updates it, and make it resend the list of events, or whatever you want

```
  addEvent(event: Event) {
    this.events.push(event);
    this.eventChanged.next(this.events.slice());
  }
```

#### Update: With example

In case we have event viewer, event editor components, and event service

Setup event service to have a subject (event changed), accessor (get events) adder (update events)

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Subject} from 'rxjs/Subject';

@Injectable()
export class EventService {

  eventChanged = new Subject<string[]>();

  events: string[] = [
    'Pizza Party',
    'Hackacthon',
    'Movie Night'
  ]
  constructor() { }

  addEvent(event: string) {
    this.events.push(event);
    this.eventChanged.next(this.events.slice());
  }

  getEvents() {
    return this.events.slice();
  }
}
```

Then component EventViewer, gets the list, as well as subscribes for any changes

**event-viewer.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {EventService} from '../event.service';
import {Subscription} from 'rxjs/Subscription';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-event-viewer',
  templateUrl: './event-viewer.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./event-viewer.component.css']
})
export class EventViewerComponent implements OnInit {

  subscription: Subscription;
  events: string[] = this.eventService.getEvents();

  constructor(private eventService: EventService) { }


  ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription = this.eventService.eventChanged
    .subscribe(
      (events: string[]) => {
        this.events = events;
      }
    )
  }

}
```

So then we render it out

**event-viewer.component.html**

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let event of events">{{event}}</li>
</ul>
```

Lastly we want an event editor component

event-editor.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {EventService} from '../event.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-event-edit',
  templateUrl: './event-edit.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./event-edit.component.css']
})
export class EventEditComponent implements OnInit {

  eventNumber: number = 1;

  constructor(private eventService: EventService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  addEvent()
  {
    this.eventService.addEvent(this.eventNumber.toString())
    this.eventNumber++;
  }

}
```

and render a button for the user to control

event-editor.component.ts

```
<button (click)="addEvent()">Add event {{eventNumber}}</button>
```

In the module of choice we'll obviously have to declare these components, enlist the provider

**app.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    EventViewerComponent,
    EventEditComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  providers: [EventService]
})
```

So then in then we render both components

```
app.component.ts

<app-event-viewer></app-event-viewer>
<app-event-edit></app-event-edit>
```

Now every time we click on button in one component, the other component gets the updated list
[image]

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work, I add `this.eventChanged.next(this.events.slice());` in mine Service constructor and I also test method `addEvent()` and `this.eventService.eventChanged.subscribe(..` didn't notice any changes. It was not called again.

Comment: @Adriano, created a complete example

Comment: @lancovici That subscribing don't works when I get data from server. Only thanks to this : `events: string[] = this.eventService.getEvents();` it displays data after page reload.

Comment: @Adriano check your rxjs in package.json, and let me know what version it is. Also do you see any errors when inspecting page?

Comment: @lancovici it's "rxjs": "^5.5.2", No I didn't notice any errors. I make subscibing works but only after I add a next 'Event'

Comment: @Adriano, Not sure how you are setup right now, maybe put it in https://stackblitz.com. in this example I'm showing you how to get the list on initialization from a service, then whenever someone update the list, the service updates list, then calls next on subject, and inputs the list. The component that needs to listen, will have to get the list inside its subscription callback.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162226/discussion-between-adriano-and-iancovici).

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
export class YourService {
    private refreshSource: Subject<boolean> = new Subject();
    public refreshStream: Observable<boolean> = this.refreshSource.asObservable();

    endpoint_url = "https://<your_backend>/api/";

    constructor(private client: HttpClient) {}

    // get collection
    cget(queryParams: any): Promise<Obj[]> {
         return this.client.get<Obj[]>(this.endpoint_url + 'objs').toPromise();
    }

    // create one object
    post(obj: Obj): Promise<Obj> {
        const res = this.client.post(
            this.endpoint_url + 'objs',
            JSON.stringify(obj),
            this.requestParams);

        return res.toPromise().then((response) => {
            obj.id = response['id'];
            this.refreshSource.next(true);
            return obj as Obj;
        });
}



export class YourComponent implements OnDestroy {
    subscriptions: Subscription[] = [];
    success:boolean;
    failure:boolean;
    loading:boolean;

    constructor(private ys: YourService) {
        this.subscriptions.push( this.ys.refreshStrem.subscribe(() => this.load()) );
    }


    async load() {
        this.yourObjs = await this.ys.cget();
    }

    async submit() {
        this.loading = true;
        try {
            const response = this.ys.post(this.obj)
            this.success = true;   
        } catch (error) {
            console.log('error', error);
            this.failure = true;
        } finally {
            this.loading = false;
        }
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.subscriptions.forEach(subscription => subscription.unsubscribe());

}
```